# How do I fix this VBA error - Command was not prepared?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running a VBA code. However, I encounter an error saying "Command was not prepared" at line:

'Copy the recordset data to the Excel worksheet
ws.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

Below is my entire VBA:

```
Private Sub UploadDataFromSQL() 
'Set variables 
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection 
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset 
Dim sql As String 
Dim row As Long 
Dim col As Long Dim ws As Worksheet

' Create a new connection object
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
'Create a new recordset object and new worksheet
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
'Set up Excel worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

'Set connection properties'
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Initial Catalog=CPR; Data Source=VNSGNWD1027007; Workstation ID=VNSGNWD1023020; User ID=sav; Password=123456789;" & _
                                            "Persist Security Info=True; Use Procedure for Prepare=1; Auto Translate=True; Packet Size=4096;" & _
                                            "Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False"
conn.Open

sql = "SELECT [ACCOUNT CREATE DATE]" & _
                ",[ACCOUNT NAME]" & _
                ",[ACCOUNT NUMBER]" & _
                ",A.[GSFA CUSTOMER ID]" & _
                ",A.[TERRITORY]" & _
                ",A.[SALES TEAM]" & _
                ",C.[LEAD SOURCE]" & _
        "FROM [CPR].[dbo].[COMET_ACCOUNT] AS A" & _
        "LEFT JOIN [CPR].[dbo].[COMET_CUSTOMER] AS C" & _
        "ON A.[GSFA CUSTOMER ID] =  C.[GSFA CUSTOMER ID]" & _
        "WHERE CAST(GETDATE() AS INT) - CAST([ACCOUNT CREATE DATE] AS INT) <=7 AND [LEAD SOURCE] = 'Customer Service'" & _
        "ORDER BY CAST(GETDATE() AS INT) - CAST([ACCOUNT CREATE DATE] AS INT) DESC"

'Execute query'
 rs.Open sql, conn
    
'Copy the recordset data to the Excel worksheet
ws.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs **---> ERROR**
 
'Close connection and recordset'
rs.Close
conn.Close

'Clean up
Set rs = Nothing
Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Please help me to debug the code. Thank you!

Comment: Your concatenated sql is missing needed spaces…

Comment: hi, could you show me how to fix it? thanks a lot

Comment: Starting from `"FROM [...]"` add a space to the left on each string.

Comment: I try but it doesn't work, still showing error of "incorrect syntax near A". I even drop SQL query into Notepad++ to find any space unnecessary but it doesn't show up any thing

Comment: There are _missing_ spaces, not unnecessary spaces. For example `...] AS A"` should be `...] AS A "` (notice the space added between `A` and `"`

Comment: Add a space before every `" & _`